# How can I add $or condition with update query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I add $or condition with update query?
example: id:1 or scope:default

```
db.users.update({$or:[{id: 1}, {scope:"default"}]}, {$set: {id: 11}}, {multi:true});
```

Comment: Your query already includes that $or condition; can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: if I use both queries separately then that specific document gets updated but if used with $OR then it doesn't give any result to update.

Comment: Your code is correct and it works fine when I try it.

Comment: Maybe adding the "specific document" details (including at least `id` and `scope` values!) would help explain your problem.

Comment: Right, can you provide a document example that should be updated but isn't @ANUPAMANETKE?